# Django query table to find Item that only exist in Parent field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I been struggling with doing a query to get the rows where a Item only exsist in Parnet field and not Child field.

This is the models.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()

class ItemRelations(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey('Item', related_name='itemchild')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Item', related_name='itemparent')
```

So I only want to filter out the Items that are not a child, but is a Parent. I call it the firstParent.

I tried so many different ways. I want to accomplish something like this.

```
firstParent = Item.objects.filter(ItemRelations_parent__is=self).exclude(ItemRelations_child__is=self)
```

Is it possible. Or does one have to make several queries and loops to manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `isnull` [filter for readability.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull)

`firstParent = Item.objects.filter(itemparent=self, itemchild__isnull=True)`

In the specific example you've given in this comment, `Item.pk` is the attribute on the `Item` class.  You want the item instance, not the class.

I believe, re-reading, that the question is:

Show the Item where the Item is a parent, but not a child.  In that case:

`firstParent = Item.objects.filter(itemparent__isnull=False, itemchild__isnull=True)` will give you the queryset of objects that match that.

You may, subsequently wish to filter it further to match other aspects.  Remember that [django querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). Don't confuse making several filters with making actual queries/database hits.

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated.

Comment: Self i not a defined name. It just refers in my example to the Item pk. If I use 'self' it gives me _Exception Value: name 'self' is not defined_. I tried with Item.pk instead of self, but it generates _int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'property'_

Comment: I've edited the answer after some further thought.  I did use the code example you used, to be fair!

Comment: Yes, I want to show items that are parents, but not a child. With this query you edited, I will get all items that's been a parent. But I will still get them if they also been a child. I want to make sure a item never ever been a child. If I would only use _itemchild__isnull=True_ I would get closer. But I also want to make sure the item been assigned a child, with other word, is a parent. With no parents itself. Don't know if that make any sense.

Comment: It doesn't, really. From the description you've given in your question, this should do it. You will get all Items that are a parent, but do not have a child ItemRelation (i.e., that related set is empty.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

```
firstParent = Item.objects.exclude(child=self).filter(parent=self)
```

write exclude before filter.

Comment: 'self' is not a namespace. In my question is represent Item. That the Item itself should exist in Parent and not in an Child. If I type ***=self*** I get _Exception Value: 
name 'self' is not defined_